# Сonditional characteristics with respect to a discrete random variable

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, expectation

160 asymmetrical coins participate in the first roll. In the second roll, only those coins on which the "eagle" fell out in the first roll participate. It is known that the probability of an eagle falling out for these asymmetric coins is 0.55. Find: 1) the mathematical expectation of the number of "eagles" that fell out in the second throw; 2) the variance of the conditional mathematical expectation of the number of "eagles" that fell out in the second throw, relative to the number of "eagles" that fell out in the first throw.

Tell me, please, where should I start solving or where can I find information, after which it will be possible to start solving the problem